# What is the domain of this area function?

Tags: calculus

Problem:

> The region in the first quadrant bounded by the curves of $y^2=x$ and $y=x$ is rotated about the y-axis to form a solid. Find the area of the largest cross section of this solid that is perpendicular to the y-axis.

[image]

For the area function, which is $A=\pi(y^2-y^4)$, what is the domain of this function? Is it $0<y<1$ or $0\leq y\leq 1$?

Comment: it would be the closed interval.

Comment: @AnuragA Why exactly?

Comment: Since area is zero at y=1 and since area is also zero on the intervals $y\geq 1$ and $y\leq 0$, can't I say the domain of the function is all y-values?

Comment: Even though the maxima won't occur at the end points but from the point of view of the problem, the function is indeed defined at the two end points, hence should be included in the domain.

Comment: The problem says, the  region **bounded** by the two curves, so you are analyzing a restricted area that lies in $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think,  the domain here it's $0\leq x\leq1.$

By AM-GM our area it's $$\pi((\sqrt{x})^2-x^2)=\pi x(1-x)\leq\pi\left(\frac{x+1-x}{2}\right)^2=\frac{\pi}{4}.$$
The equality occurs for $x=1-x$, which says that we got a maximal value.

Comment: Sorry how does your last sentence prove what the domain is, I have a hard time understanding.

Comment: @user532874 See your picture.

Answer (score 1):

To find the extrema of a continuous function (like the area function $A$ here) over some domain, only the values at the domain's boundary and the critical points within the domain need be considered.

Evaluating $A$ at the endpoints of the domain $y=0,1$ yields $0$ either way, while the area function is positive at (say) $y=0.5$, so the endpoints do not really matter here.